# What are the differences between normal and classic difficulties?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I can't seem to find a good list of info of all the changes that classic mode offers over normal other than that 'its much harder'.  Does any of the enemy AI improve in classic mode?  Do enemies have more health and do more damage?  Does the panic meter increase faster for countries?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find a detailed overview of the differences between all four difficulties in [this thread on the 2K forums](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?150076-Differences-in-Difficulties).

Here is what that thread says about Normal and Classic:

> Normal:
>
> 1. Base global panic starts at 0
> 2. Most minor alien activity raises panic by 1 in left unchecked with some events doing up to 3
> 3. Your soldiers have no bonus hitpoints
> 4. Aliens have their AI mostly unshackled
> 5. Soldiers cost $10
>
> Classic:
>
> 1. Base global panic starts at 8 (1 per location)
> 2. If unchecked alien activity causes at least 1 panic, but will often cause 2 or 3
> 3. Your soldiers have -1 hitpoint
> 4. All aliens receive bonuses hit hitpoints, accuracy, critical change and / or damage.
> 5. Alien AI is unshackled
> 6. You don't receive officer training school for free. You must unlock and purchase it.
> 7. There are even more aliens per map
> 8. Soldiers cost $15

Comment: I'm playing classic ironman mode and there is officer training school.

Comment: @Baboloo Maybe the officer training school is part of the tutorial?

Comment: Indeed, probably we need to distinguish between the difficulty levels *and* whether the tutorial is chosen. Switched to Community Wiki if you like.

Comment: From watching [this video](http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/xcom-enemy-unknown/1226273p1.html) in which Jake Solomon discusses the differences, it means you don't get the officer training school *for free*. You have to unlock it (with a high ranked soldier) and build it on Classic. But it's not like it's completely missing from Classic difficulty.

Comment: yes.  That is what I experienced.  I did not start with an officer training school on classic mode.

Comment: turns out steam vents are random.  my latest classic game started out with 3 (1 of them on level 2!)

Answer (score 5):

Other differences

**Normal**

- you start with 37 energy in your base
- satellites cost 100 to begin with
- you may have more open spots for construction in the base

**Classic**

- you start with 30 energy in your base
- satellites cost 100

Answer (score 4):

My answer is based on reading impressions/ my impressions (mind, my own classic mode game is barely started), and [this interview](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/10/06/xcom-s-classic-ironman-mode-is-an-even-match-for-its-creator.aspx):

1. On the strategic layer, aliens expand more quickly.  The panic meter will increase more rapidly.  Mission rewards will be smaller.
2. In battles, aliens have better AI and *some* will have more health.  They will do a better job of making use of abilities and more aliens will attack at once (as opposed to coming in smaller groups in normal, e.g.).  The interview talks about how Thin Men get an extra health point to make them grenade proof, but floaters did not get extra health.  Apparently morale will be more severe in battles as well, which means more panics when things go bad (as they invariably will).